# Threading and timers inside an emulator

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, gdi, emulation

I'm developing a Chip-8 emulator in C#, I have completed partially almost every aspect but there is something I'm still wondering about speed control of the emulator.

What I'm doing now is assuming that I get 60 frames per second, I use a timer that fires 1/60 seconds in the following manner (pseudocode):

```
timer_ticked()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Settings.CyclesPerFrame; i++)
    {
        EmulateCycle();
    }

    if (IsDrawFlagSet)
    {
        DrawGraphics();
    }
}
```

I'm using a high resolution timer called microtimer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer , I believe that the timer doesn't wait for timer_ticked to finish to fire the next cycle (fon instance, creating a new thread) and I'm having an issue with threads and the form since trying to paint to a window with GDI (using the control.GetGraphics() method) seems to be threadsafe, but trying to create an SDLDotNet approach (just an example) doesnt.

Which approach do you think is best to control the speed of an emulator without getting into timer thread insanity?

PS: You can find the source code of the emulator in GitHub: https://github.com/AlFranco/C8POC

Thank you!

Comment: The pseudocode doesn't guarantee 60 frames per second for the simple fact you are at the mercy of the operating system and the processor itself.  I would be very shocked if `GetGraphics()`was actually threadsafe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So 16,6ms is too precise for a normal timer to be handled? Do you know any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you tick method is being called again before it's done, the problem isn't with your timer. It's because the processing is taking longer than that 16.6 ms. Getting a better timer isn't going to solve your problem.

That said, you can prevent reentrancy in a couple of ways.

You could just disable the timer when you enter the callback, and re-enable it when you're done. That'll prevent multiple invocations:

```
timer_ticked()
{
    timer.Enabled = false;
    // do stuff here
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Note that this doesn't give you a perfect 16.6 ms tick frequency. Rather, the next tick will occur 16.6 ms (approximately) after you enable the timer. Your real period is 16.6 ms plus however long it takes to do the processing.

The only time this would fail is if the `timer_ticked` method wasn't called before the next tick happened.

If you want to guarantee that you can't get concurrent ticks, you can use a `System.Threading.Timer` and set it up as a one-shot (no periodic signaling). For example:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(timer_tick, null, 16, -1);
```

The `-1` in the last parameter tells it not to be a periodic timer. It'll fire once and stop.

Then, in your timer tick:

```
timer_tick()
{
    // do stuff
    // restart the timer
    myTimer.Change(16, -1);
}
```

### Edit

You can't easily tell the timer not to issue a tick if the handler is still processing the previous tick. You can, however, prevent the timer tick handler from doing anything on that subsequent tick. You simply use a `Monitor`:

```
private object timerLock = new object();
timer_ticked()
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(timerLock))
        return;
    try
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(timerLock);
    }
}
```

The problem with such a solution is that if your timer is set of 16 ms and the handler takes 17 ms, then your effective update rate will be once every 32 ms, because the second tick is essentially ignored. You're better off with the one-shot timer deal.

Another possibility is to use a `Stopwatch` to time how long your handler takes, and subtract that from the next delay period:

```
timer_ticked()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    // do stuff
    timer.Change(16-sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, -1);
}
```

But it's not quite that simple. If it takes longer than 16 ms for the handler to do its thing, you'll end up with a negative delay. So you'll want:

```
var delayTime = Math.Max(0, 16 - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
timer.Change(delayTime, -1);
```

But again, if your handler regularly takes longer than the timer delay, then this isn't going to help you. You'll either have to reduce your timer frequency (i.e. make a longer delay) or optimize your processing code.

Comment: I get what you mean. Would there be a better approach to simulate the ticks of a processor in emulation? The only idea left I have based on what I thought about this is to implement a timer that fires every x miliseconds only if the previous tick function has finished and fire immediately when that happens if it's waiting. Again, I'm not tied to the approach above, I think it would be good to discuss other alternatives if you think of any :). Thank you!